Carleson's theorem: proof of a lemma
I am reading the paper of Michael Lacey called "Carleson's theorem: proof, complements, variations" 1, on Carleson's theorem in Fourier analysis. At the bottom of page 20 at the beginning of section 6: "The Tree Lemma" it says:
Consider the maximal function
$$\text{M }f:=\sup_{I\in
\mathcal{D}}1_I|\langle f, \chi_I\rangle|.$$
It is well known that this is bounded on $L^2$. A proof follows.
But the proof doesn't convince me. In particular I don't see how the inequality
$$2\sum_{I\in\mathcal{D}}\sum_{|J|\leq|I|}1_{E(I)}\langle \chi_I, \chi_J\rangle \langle 1_{E(J)}, f\rangle\lesssim\sum_{I\in\mathcal{D}}1_{E(I)}\langle f,\chi_I\rangle$$
follows. So far I haven't been able to come up with a proof that $M$ is bounded on $L^2$. Can someone help me?
Edit:
Let me clarify some of the notations here: $\mathcal{D}$ is the set of dyadic intervals
$$\mathcal{D}:=\{[j2^k, (j+1)2^k)|j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\},$$
and $\chi_I$ is a translation and dilation of a basic function $\chi$ of the form
$$\chi(x)= (1+|x|)^{-\kappa},$$
for a fixed large $\kappa$, and
$$\chi_I(x):=\frac{1}{|I|}\chi((x-c(I))/|I|),$$
where $|I|$ is the length of the dyadic interval $I$, and $c(I)$ is the center.

There is a wonderful button in the edit tools on MO called "insert citation". It's really great to use this button so that everyone knows exactly what you're looking at!

$M$ is dominated by a (dyadic) Hardy--Littlewood maximal function, so it is indeed well known that it is bounded on $L^2$. As for Lacey's proof, you need the inequality
$$
\sum_{|J|\le |I|} \langle \chi_I, \chi_J \rangle \int_{E(J)} f \lesssim \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_I f.
$$ for nonnegative functions $f$. The sets $E(J)$ are pairwise disjoint --- hence it is enough to prove that for any fixed $J$ with $|J|\le |I|$ we have
$$
\int_{E(J)} \langle \chi_I, \chi_J \rangle f \lesssim \int_{E(J)} \chi_I f.
$$
And now we can simply compare the expressions under the integral: since $E(J)\subset J$ we need that for any $t\in J$
\begin{equation}
\langle \chi_I, \chi_J \rangle \lesssim \chi_I(t).
\end{equation}
Suppose that $J\subset I+m|I|$ ($m\in\mathbb{Z}$). The RHS in the above inequality is equivalent to $\frac{1}{|I|}(1+|m|)^{-\kappa}$. As for the LHS, for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$
\int_{I+n|I|} \chi_I \chi_J \lesssim \frac{1}{|I|}(1+|n|)^{-\kappa}\int_{I+n|I|}\chi_J.
$$
For $n\in\{m-1, m, m+1\}$ this quantity is indeed dominated by $\frac{1}{|I|}(1+|m|)^{-\kappa}$ (just because $\int_\mathbb{R}\chi_J\lesssim 1$), while for all other values of $n$ the values of $\chi_J$ on $I+n|I|$ can be pointwise estimated by $\frac{1}{|J|}\Big(\frac{|n-m||I|}{|J|} \Big)^{-\kappa}$, hence
$$
\int_{I+n|I|}\chi_J \lesssim  \frac{|I|}{|J|}\Big(\frac{|n-m||I|}{|J|} \Big)^{-\kappa} \le |n-m|^{-\kappa}
\lesssim (1+|n-m|)^{-\kappa}.
$$
Overall,
$$
\langle \chi_I, \chi_J \rangle \lesssim \frac{1}{|I|} \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} (1+|n|)^{-\kappa} (1+|n-m|)^{-\kappa} \lesssim \frac{1}{|I|}(1+|m|)^{-\kappa},
$$
and the inequality is proved.

$\chi_I$ is not defined as $1_I/|I|$, but thank you for the link to the Hardy-littlewood maximal function, I will give it a think.

@Alexander, you are right, I overlooked the definition. I edited my answer, now the proof is less trivial.

Cool! Thank you for helping me!
